# How to sort by 2 variables and select by 1 variable to create a dataframe

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I would like to sort the data by`Timestamp` first, then by`group_Id`. From there, I would like to select all corresponding data for `Timestamp` 1/1/18 to 7/1/18 and save it as a Dataframe called `df1` so that I could load it into a machine learning model.

My data looks like this.

```
Id      Timestamp       Data  group_Id
5999    1/1/18 0:00     25.5    101
6000    1/1/18 0:00     25      101
6001    1/1/18 0:00     27      52
6002    1/1/18 0:00     26.5    52
6003    1/1/18 0:00     25.5    50
6004    1/1/18 0:00     25      50
6005    1/1/18 0:00     37      14
6006    1/1/18 0:00     36.5    14
6007    1/1/18 0:00     30.5    85
6008    1/1/18 0:00     30      85
...          ...        ...     ..
```

Please advise how I could do this. Do I have to export the Dataframe `df1` from Colab? Thank you.

In reply to @MyNameIsCaleb answer, I ran the reproducible data and obtained the following result, but there are 2 issues: 
1) group_Id is not sorted
2) the number of rows reduced(sorry I think I was not clear about my purpose. I wanted to sort data and extract 10 days of data which lies in a particular time period, say 2018/08/08 - 2018/08/14)and make this a new Dataframe with all the rows in between the dates.

```
     Id  Timestamp  Data  group_Id
3  6002 2019-02-01  26.5        52
4  6003 2019-03-01  25.5        50
1  6000 2019-04-01  25.0       101
5  6004 2019-05-01  25.0        50
6  6005 2019-06-01  37.0        14
7  6006 2019-07-01  36.5        14
```

On the actual data, it gives an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-e7bd6eb249eb> in <module>()
      2 day1 = datetime.strptime('2018-08-13', '%Y-%m-%d')
      3 day2 = datetime.strptime('2018-08-19', '%Y-%m-%d')
----> 4 df1 = df.loc[df['Timestamp'].between(day1, day2)].sort_values(by=['Timestamp', 'group_Id'])

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_label_or_level_values(self, key, axis)
   1704             values = self.axes[axis].get_level_values(key)._values
   1705         else:
-> 1706             raise KeyError(key)
   1707 
   1708         # Check for duplicates

KeyError: 'group_Id'
```

I am not sure what could have gone wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using

```
df2 = df.loc[df['Timestamp'].between(date1, date2)].sort_values(by=['Timestamp', 'group_Id'])
```

`.between` is as named, you must use datetime objects for it to process properly with your datetime column.
`sort_values` can do multiple columns at once.

You want to sort after you select between so that you aren't sorting every item and instead just the ones selected unless you plan to continue using `df` and need it sorted as well, in which case just put that before on the main `df`.

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Id': [5999, 6000, 6001, 6002, 6003, 6004, 6005, 6006, 6007, 6008],
    'Timestamp': ['8/1/19 00:00', '4/1/19 00:00', '1/1/19 00:00', '2/1/19 00:00', '3/1/19 00:00', '5/1/19 00:00', '6/1/19 00:00', '7/1/19 00:00', '9/1/19 00:00', '10/1/19 00:00'],
    'Data': [25.5, 25, 27, 26.5, 25.5, 25, 37, 36.5, 30.5, 30],
    'group_Id': [101, 101, 52, 52, 50, 50, 14, 14, 85, 85]
})

df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format='%m/%d/%y %H:%M')

date1 = datetime.strptime('2019-01-31', '%Y-%m-%d')
date2 = datetime.strptime('2019-07-31', '%Y-%m-%d')

df2 = df.loc[df['Timestamp'].between(date1, date2)].sort_values(by=['Timestamp', 'group_Id'])
```

Comment: Hi @MyNameIsCaleb, thank you for your answer. I incurred a problem with the code. I've put the details in the question.

Comment: @nilsinelabore `group_Id` is the column name based on your example data. Replace it with the proper column name if it isn't actually `group_Id` in your real data. Once you do that, it will be sorted appropriately as well. If `group_Id` is something other than a column then you would need to make it a column. If you want to limit the number of rows you can use `.head(n)` where `n` is number of rows.

Comment: I've replaced `group_Id` with the actual column name and it is a column. I guess there might be other issues...

Comment: According to the error you posted you didn't change `group_Id` in the code which is why it didn't find the column since it isn't named that in your data.

Comment: So that `KeyError` happens when you attempt to sort on a column name that doesn't exist. I can't help you more than that really.